# Javascript select boxes based on previous selection

Tags: javascript, select, onclick

How can I ensure that this does NOT open in a new window??

```
onclick="ob=this.form.table;window.open(ob.options[ob.selectedIndex].value)"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want it open in a same window you need to write

```
onclick="ob=this.form.table;window.location.href=(ob.options[ob.selectedIndex].value)"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should replace it with:

```
onclick="ob=this.form.table;document.location=ob.options[ob.selectedIndex].value;"/>
```

Window.open() opens a new window; document.location changes the page in the current window.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want it to open in the same window?

if so use `window.location`